# Receiving Jquery POST data in Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, post

**Edit** See the accepted answer below for the fix. I also had to remove the line `contentType: 'appliction/json',` from my POST request.

I'm trying to send a string to Node.js / Express, but `req.body` is undefined server-side.

Client jQuery:

```
$.post({
        traditional: true,
        url: '/matches',
        contentType: 'appliction/json',
        data: viewedProfiles,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
```

Express:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/matches', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body) // this is undefined
  var loadedProfiles = []
  loadedProfiles.push(req.body.viewedProfiles)
  console.log('loadedProfiles')
  console.log(loadedProfiles)
```

I've tried:

- not specifying 'dataType'
- setting `data: JSON.stringify(viewProfiles)`
- splitting the string into an array on the client, and then having jQuery stringify it
- looking for req.params instead of req.body (clutching at straws)

I can see the XHR request in dev tools, and it contains the string I'm expecting.

What super obvious thing am I missing to send the data to Express?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `connect` middleware running in your page?

Comment: I don't but I have jQuery data posts running successfully elsewhere in the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your server side code looks fine but you need to use `$.ajax()` rather than  `$.post()` function because `$.post()` function send data into url (with url encoded). So your JQuery code would be

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/matches',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({"viewedProfiles": viewedProfiles}),
        success: function(response){
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Yes, that really helped me! I also had to remove the line `contentType: 'appliction/json',` before it would work.

Answer (score 7):

I've configured an exact same setup. And code below works:

```
var profiles = { 'data' : 'hello' };

$.post({
        traditional: true,
        url: '/matches',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify( profiles ),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){ console.log( response ); }
} );
```

My nodejs engine:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post( '/matches' , function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body) // this outputs: { data: 'hello' }
} );
```

Btw, There is a typo where your contentType is, 'applic**A**tion/json'